# Romper la ejecución de una función - Evento onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Buen día, tengo un problema con el siguiente ejercicio en JS, estoy en el tema de manejar eventos del ratón, en este caso es un evento de click, utilizando onclick y mi nombre de función que ejecuta algo.

Tengo un HTML básico, solo para exponer el problema que se me presenta, tengo un boton y un div, en este último se agregara contenido dinámico, contenido que se creará con JS.

Tengo una variable llamada contador combinado con una sentencia if, cuando el contador acumule el valor númerico 10, este entra en el condicional y detiene la ejecución de la función llamada "ejecutar".

Intente colocando un "break", por desgracia no funciona, ¿que puedo hacer para detener la ejecución de esta función?... de antemano gracias por el apoyo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>::JS::</title>
</head>

<body>

<section>
    <button id="boton" onclick="ejecutar()">Presioname</button>
    <div id="contenidoDinamico"></div>
</section>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    /*
        En la primera parte se crear una variable llamada "conteo", la cual al almacenar una cantidad de 10
        ingresa en la evaluación de una sentencia if, la cuál debe romper la ejecución de la función.
    */
    let conteo=0;
    let contenidoDinamico=document.querySelector('#contenidoDinamico');

    function ejecutar(){
        let nuevoTexto=document.createElement('p');
        nuevoTexto.textContent=(conteo+1) + '.- Soy un texto desde JS';
        contenidoDinamico.appendChild(nuevoTexto);
        conteo=conteo+1;

        if(conteo==10){
            document.getElementById('boton').textContent='STOP';
            break; // Intentando romper la ejecución de la función.
        }
    }




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas bien, debes poner las acciones dentro del `if` y el `stop` en un `else`, en el cual, al cumplirse la condición, haces lo que requieras.

```js
let conteo = 0;
let contenidoDinamico = document.querySelector('#contenidoDinamico');

function ejecutar() {
  if (conteo <= 10) {
    let nuevoTexto = document.createElement('p');
    nuevoTexto.textContent = (conteo) + '.- Soy un texto desde JS';
    contenidoDinamico.appendChild(nuevoTexto);
    conteo++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('boton').textContent = 'STOP';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>::JS::</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <button id="boton" onclick="ejecutar()">Presioname</button>
    <div id="contenidoDinamico"></div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo y el tiempo que dedicaste a responder mi duda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por los animos, me motiva a continuar aprendiendo más sobre JS, después de intentar e investigar por internet, intente lo siguiente, en esta ocasión con algunas variantes, en la condición del contador llamado "conteo" al almacenar un valor de 10, este ejecuta una función "removeEventListener" para detener la ejecución de la función.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>::JS::</title>
</head>

<body>

<section>
    <button id="boton">Presioname</button>
    <div id="contenidoDinamico"></div>
</section>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var boton=document.getElementById('boton');
    var contenidoDinamico=document.getElementById('contenidoDinamico');
    var conteo=0;

    var ejecuta=function(){
        let nuevoTexto=document.createElement('p');
        nuevoTexto.textContent=(conteo+1) + '.- Soy un texto desde JS';
        contenidoDinamico.appendChild(nuevoTexto);
        conteo +=1;

        if(conteo==10){
            boton.textContent='STOP';
            boton.removeEventListener('click',ejecuta);
        }
    }

    boton.addEventListener('click',ejecuta);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```